# Logging in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-3.1, asp.net-core-middleware

I am building a Log mechanism in ASP.Net Core 3.1. Main idea is to log every activity per request in DB where property requestId (GUID) is the same for repeated/same requests.

For example I have sql table definition:

- **RecordId** - generated per request
- **RequestId** - has same value for repeated/same requests
- **Status** - 200, 400 etc...
- **DateCreated** - time when request is logged

What I need help is how to get the same RequestId for repeated/same requests ?

So far, in my project I created a Request Middleware and try with:

- correlationId - from NuGet package CorrelationId
- traceId - from HttpContext.TraceIdentifier (is not even in GUID format, regardless of that, I tried to see if I can use something to rely on)

Both of them are generating unique id, which I don't need.
Any suggestions or example would help.

Comment: Only you can determine what counts as a "repeated/same" request. You could use a hash of the URI + request body, if all requests are in the same format (it's possible to have equal request parameters, but one in XML and the other in JSON).

Comment: Thats it, I totaly forgot about the hash. I am only using the URI and convert to hash code for example: https://localhost:3030/api/attachment/Standard   -> 1832152149
and use hash to generated GUID. Not need to check if request is in the same format becouse contentType is always JSON. Thank you :)

Comment: Ok there is one issue with a hash. If I run api for the second time then it will generate different hash regardless if input value is the same. Any fix for that ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the relevant code.

Comment: Question is updated. I could use Length of the url and pass down to generate guid - that way I will get same uuid for repeated/same url, but I am concern if I get same length even if url is different.

Comment: I think I got it. I only need to change from Encoding.Default.GetBytes(url) to Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(url). Also I don't need Hash only need to pass url. Now it's working when I re-run api, also even if url has different string combinations but same length it will work. CodeCaster - Thank you for showing me the path to enlightenment :)

Answer (score 0):

**ANSWER:**

```
var url = "https://localhost:3030/api/attachment/Standard";

Guid requestId;
using (MD5 md5 = MD5.Create())
{
    byte[] hash = md5.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(url));

    requestId = new Guid(hash);
}
```

Resolve:

1. Generate same requestID for repeated requests
2. Don't use GetHashCode due to limitations when re-run the api -> it will generate different code even if the url is the same.
3. Consider if we have two urls ending with the same action length 'Standard and Examples' will get different bytes output:

- Standard is [53, 74, 61, 6e, 64, 61, 72, 64] bytes
- Examples is [45, 78, 61, 6d, 70, 6c, 65, 73] bytes